# When should I use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I feel like I should know this, but I don't and it always confuses me.

When browsing through sample code and tutorials, I will sometimes see AppDelegates that have a

`@property UIWindow* window`,

which is then `@synthesized` and followed up with a

`[window setRootViewController:controllerToBeSet]`

`[window makeKeyAndVisible]`

other apps will not have a single line of code anywhere in the delegate.

I understand that the friendly arrow in the storyboard denotes the root view controller. 
So are packed AppDelegates just for nib-based projects?

I need some clarity on the norms for using the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate method and the way views are initially set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct. The following quote is from Apple's docs (in "Using View Controllers in Your App"):

> The Main Storyboard Initializes Your App’s User Interface
>
> The main storyboard is defined in the app’s Information property list
>   file. If a main storyboard is declared in this file, then when your
>   app launches, iOS performs the following steps:
>
> It instantiates a window for you. It loads the main storyboard and
>   instantiates its initial view controller. It assigns the new view
>   controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes
>   the window visible on the screen.

If you don't use a storyboard, then you need to instantiate the window, set up the window's root view controller, and make the window visible in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. You get that from the template if you start a single view project with storyboards turned off.